# Remove migration files and recreate Initial.cs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-migrations

I've been using migrations for a while now, and I've ended up with a bunch of migration files. I've been having the trouble that my Seed method duplicates the data (when trying to use the Id as an "identifier"), when I only want to create the data once.

Now I was thinking of removing all the migration files and recreating the initial one to tidy up a bit. I was also planning on seeding the data in the Up() method using SQL(), instead of using the Seed() method.

I've already got a bunch of sites running for paying clients. I don't want to risk ending up in a situation where I have to chose from not being able to update the db schema, and having to drop the clients data (that would look really bad on my part).

I feel a but unsure about this whole migration thing. I've had occurrences in the early stages of development where the migrations got screwed up and I had to drop/recreate the db.

So my questions boils down to...will I encounter problems updating my already running sites if I remove the migration files and recreate one big initial migration?

This is my current Configuration.cs. I'm using the option in Web Deploy to "Execute Code Migrations" on Application_Start():

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<BandPage.Models.BandPageContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void Seed(BandPage.Models.BandPageContext context)
        {
            List<SiteSettings> siteSettings = new List<SiteSettings>
            {
                new SiteSettings
                {
                    Title = "Page title",
                    MetaKeywords = "",
                    MetaDescription = "",
                    MetaLanguage = "en",
                    Favicon = "",
                    FooterText = "",
                    BackgroundImage = "",
                    HeaderImage = "",
                    FooterImage = "",
                    BackgroundColor = "255,255,255",
                    ContainerColor = "0,0,0",
                    ContainerOpacity = 7,
                    HeadingColor = "0,0,0",
                    TextColor = "0,0,0",
                    LinkColor = "0,0,255",
                    HeadingFont = "Verdana",
                    HeadingSize = "8",
                    TextFont = "Verdana",
                    TextSize = "6",
                    ContainerWidth = 800,
                    CustomCSS = ""
                }
            };
            siteSettings.ForEach(s => context.SiteSettings.AddOrUpdate(i => i.SiteSettingsId, s));
            context.SaveChanges();

            // add fonts to database
            List<Font> fonts = new List<Font>
            {
                new Font { Name = "Impact", FontFamily = "Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif" },
                new Font { Name = "Comic Sans", FontFamily = "'Comic Sans MS', cursive, sans-serif" },
                new Font { Name = "Palatino", FontFamily = "'Palatino Linotype', 'Book Antiqua', Palatino, serif" },
                new Font { Name = "Tahoma", FontFamily = "Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif" },
                new Font { Name = "Century Gothic", FontFamily = "Century Gothic, sans-serif" },
                new Font { Name = "Lucida Sans", FontFamily = "'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif" },
                new Font { Name = "Arial Black", FontFamily = "'Arial Black', Gadget, sans-serif" },
                new Font { Name = "Times New Roman", FontFamily = "'Times New Roman', Times, serif" },
                new Font { Name = "Arial Narrow", FontFamily = "'Arial Narrow', sans-serif" },
                new Font { Name = "Verdana", FontFamily = "Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif" },
                new Font { Name = "Cooperplate Gothic", FontFamily = "Copperplate, 'Copperplate Gothic Light', sans-serif" },
                new Font { Name = "Lucida Console", FontFamily = "'Lucida Console', Monaco, monospace" },
                new Font { Name = "Gill Sans", FontFamily = "'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', sans-serif" },
                new Font { Name = "Trebuchet MS", FontFamily = "'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, sans-serif" },
                new Font { Name = "Courier New", FontFamily = "'Courier New', Courier, monospace" },
                new Font { Name = "Arial", FontFamily = "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" },
                new Font { Name = "Georgia", FontFamily = "Georgia, Serif" },
                new Font { Name = "Helvetica", FontFamily = "'Helvetica Neue', 'Lucida Grande', Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif" }

            };
            fonts.ForEach(s => context.Fonts.AddOrUpdate(i => i.Name, s));
            context.SaveChanges();


            // add fixed pages like "Home", "Contact" etc
            List<MenuItemPage> menuItemPages = new List<MenuItemPage>
            {
                new MenuItemPage { PageName = "", PageId = 0, Slug = "" },
                new MenuItemPage { PageName = "Blog", PageId = 0, Slug = "blog" },
                new MenuItemPage { PageName = "Home", PageId = 0, Slug = "" },
                new MenuItemPage { PageName = "Contact", PageId = 0, Slug = "contact" },
                new MenuItemPage { PageName = "Shows", PageId = 0, Slug = "tour" },
                new MenuItemPage { PageName = "Store", PageId = 0, Slug = "store" },
                new MenuItemPage { PageName = "Image gallery", PageId = 0, Slug = "gallery" },
            };
            menuItemPages.ForEach(s => context.MenuItemPages.AddOrUpdate(i => i.PageName, s));
            context.SaveChanges();

        }
    }
```

Why do I end up with multiple records of SiteSettings? The other ones work as they should. I just can't get it to work when using the Id as identifier. I just wan't to create one row in the SiteSettings table (for some initial values), and not create any more rows.

The sites are a CMS system where every site has it's own SQL CE database.

Hope you can take the time to help me!

/Mikael

Answer (score 0):

Entity framework should be checking whether SiteSettingsId already exists in the database. If it is database generated then entity framework will check whether zero exists and if it doesn't go ahead and insert the data, so it will always insert.

The other AddOrUpdates work because you have specified a natural key that is not database generated. You could add a natural key to the SiteSettings class

Comment: So would you recommend creating a specific column just for that purpose? Cause I can't use one of the existing values right, since all of those can and will be changed by the user.

Comment: You could use SiteSettingsID if you stop  generating it in the database. But remember that if you run the Seed method on a live database then the AddOrUpdate will update the values that the user has changed

Comment: BTW, In my own database I have a Settings table that has columns for key and value. That means that I don't have to change the schema every time I need a new setting

Comment: That was why I'm thinking of switching to doing the seeding in the migration files by using SQL("INSERT.."). Do you have any tips what you might think will happen with my already deployed sites if I do what I described earlier in the post?

Comment: I've not deployed my website to production yet but putting fixed data in usinq sql("INSERT..") in the UP method in the migration files does make sense to me.See the note on this page: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/preparing-databases  I think I'll keep the Seed method for test only. And I might add compiler directives to ensure it never gets to live.